# Como colocar driver do opencv no intellij

Tags: java, ubuntu, opencv, intellij-idea, ocr

Boa noite, estou tentando usar a livraria opencv no java mas estou obtendo erros ao colocar o driver no intellij. Já instalei o opencv e adicionei a livraria nas dependências mas continuo tendo erros.
Estou usando o ubuntu 22.04.
Alguém pode me ajudar por favor?
Agredeço desde já!

O erro:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no opencv_java470 in java.library.path: /usr/java/packages/lib:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2429)
at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:818)
at java.base/java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1989)
at ImageToText.ImageToText.<clinit>(ImageToText.java:7)
```

Process finished with exit code 1